# Start services at boot

Tags: 2.1-eclair, boot, services, auto-start

How to make applications start at boot? I have at least 2 which I'd like to start automatically but they don't (I need to manually start them to have services run in background):

- [Skype](http://www.skype.com)
- [Lookout](https://www.mylookout.com)

Comment: (I'm flagging it as a duplicate since while this answer is correct, the answer on there is more complete)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing for this is going to be [tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/). Best three bucks you will ever spend on an Android phone.

Comment: Ok. I was going to buy that anyway. One more reason to use it.

Comment: @Maciej It's *highly* customizable

Comment: @Bryan: I know. I will have my phone replaced this week to different colour so I will refrain from buying it till then. For sure it is app on top of my TODO list.